# How to put 3D animations in HTML looping and change smoothly (using keyframes) to another animation when clicked?

Tags: html, animation

The idea is that there'll be a 3D animation looping (an idle character, probably rotating) and it will change to another animation when someone hovers the cursor over it (say, the character getting nervous), and another animation when clicked (say, the character startling). But if I use the old way of just changing the video it will look kind of weird because it will change drastically most of the time, how do I make this transition look good?

I'm kind of new to HTML so maybe it's easier than what I think, but I really have no idea of how to achieve this. Thank you in advance for your answers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options, make it an actual 3d model (hard) or control the flow of the video and wait for the video to finish before showing the next part/animation. Going down that route would require you to use HTML5 video tags for the video and you would have to look into the [javascript API it exposes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) to control it. It's not terribly hard, but too broad an interface to cover in this answer.

Comment: I do have the 3D model, it's modeled and animated by me :) I'm more a 3D modeler than a programmer... soo, I would need a little more explanation hehehe..

Comment: It's not the 3D model part itself that's hard. Learning OpenGL and building the skeleton system in javascript to morph the animation is the hard part. PS. Added an link to the interface in the answer.

Comment: oooh ._.
Well, thanks for the link, that's exactly what I was looking for! :D